# subform inside subform in module

Tags: php, module, xml, module-params

I have the following XML in my module:

```
<fieldset name="activities" label="Activity Details">
    <field name="image" type="media" directory="images/location" />
    <field name="title" type="text" default="" label="Activity Name" description="Enter Activity Name" filter="raw" />
    <field name="intro" type="textarea" default="" label="Enter intro details" description="" filter="raw"/>
    <field name="links" type="subform" formsource="modules/mod_activities/links.xml" multiple="true" label="Links" description="" />
</fieldset>
```

then the links.xml subform looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset name="links" label="Links">
        <field name="menulink" type="menuitem" default="45" label="Select a menu item to show" description="Select a menu item" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have called them in my module PHP file:

```
$activities = $params->get('activities');
$links = $params->get('links');
```

I then call them in a foreach loop in the default.php as follows:

```
<div id="activities" class="jl-child-width-expand@s" jl-grid>
<?php foreach ($activities as $activity) : ?>
    <div class="jl-card">
        <div class="jl-card-media-top">
            <img src="<?php echo $activity->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $activity->title; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="jl-card-body jl-padding-remove">
            <h3 class="jl-card-title jl-text-primary jl-margin-small-bottom"><?php echo $activity->title; ?></h3>
            <?php echo $activity->intro; ?>

        </div>
        <div class="jl-card-footer">
            <?php var_dump($links); ?>
            <?php var_dump($links); ?>
            <?php foreach ($links as $link) : ?>

                <?php echo $link->menulink; ?>
                <div id="links">
                    <?php var_dump($links); ?>
                </div>

                <a href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-text"><?php echo $link->menulink; ?></a>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

'image', 'title' and 'intro' are showing in the frontend, but none of the links are showing. From my var_dump() I'm just getting NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the link fields the same way you're accessing other fields, through the main `activities` field.

```
<?php foreach ((array) $activities as $activity) : ?>
    <?php foreach ((array) $activity->links as $link) : ?>
        <?php echo $link->menulink; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```